# Face orientation shows some faces darker blue and baking does not work correctly on those faces

Tags: normals, texture-baking

What's wrong with this?
I'm trying ao baking but it does not work on those faces.
I have already tested merging verts by distance but it does not make any change.
[image]

Comment: Solved, I was keeping mirror modifier enabled ;)